# Algorithm for solving sparse linear system in C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I need to solve the heat equation for 2D object using C++. I've found many sources explaining the mathematics behind it. I am using the Crank-Nicholson scheme, but given that I need a 1001 x 1001 discretization, the resulting linear system is huge and memory would blow in case of a "traditional" implementation.

Therefore, I am recurring to methods for solving sparse linear systems. I have been looking online and cannot find any source explaining an algorithm to solve this sparse system efficiently. I've found several packages that do solve it (like [csparse](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html), [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), [SciPy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/main/scipy/sparse/linalg/_dsolve/SuperLU) under-the-hood implementation), but found no theoretical explanation to really code it myself. For the moment I am trying to do "reverse engineering" on the source code of [SuperLU](https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu).

What I am looking for is an algorithm that you may know to solve sparse linear systems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This site doesn't do research for people - you might want to check out https://scicomp.stackexchange.com - though I suspect your question is probably off topic there too.

Comment: How would a million nodes "blow memory" ? You don't even need an explicit representation of sparseness.

Comment: Since you mentioned SuperLU (which, BTW sounds like overkill for 1000x1000 matrices), it literally comes with a [user guide](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/superlu/ug.pdf) and a [technical report](https://portal.nersc.gov/project/sparse/xiaoye-web/slu_ilu.pdf) containing references etc.

Comment: @YvesDaoust since I am working with Crank-Nicholson I need to access both t and t+1 at the same time, so in Ax=B $x \in \mathcal{R}^{1 000 000}$ so $A \in \mathcal{R}^{1 000 000 x 1 000 000}$, no?

Comment: @nico_so: what about the sparseness ?!

Comment: @YvesDaoust the matrix A will only contain at most 5 non-zeros per row (except for the first and last rows). If I use a dense representation of A it will be all zeros save those few entries, which is an extremely suboptimal use of memory.

Comment: Only you speaks of a dense representation, though you mention Crank-Nicholson !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about numerical methods, not programming.